# Is there a way to declare PostgreSQL array columns that prevent duplicates?

Tags: postgresql

In other words, is there a way to make an array column to work like a set, that is, when a duplicate value is added to it, it is simply ignored?

One possibility is to use triggers or to ensure uniqueness of elements when a `SELECT` is performed, but ideally I want the array to act more like a set.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. The usual way in a relational database would be to create proper 1:n relationship where you can control uniqueness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible. But, you can use a own append function, that appends only unique values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION append_unique(anyarray, anyelement)
RETURNS anyarray AS $$
  SELECT CASE WHEN $2 = ANY($1) THEN $1 ELSE $1 || $2 END; 
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

postgres=# SELECT append_unique(ARRAY[1,2,3], 4);
 append_unique 
---------------
 {1,2,3,4}
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT append_unique(ARRAY[1,2,3,4], 4);
 append_unique 
---------------
 {1,2,3,4}
(1 row)
```

Comment: In the second select I think you mean `SELECT append_unique(ARRAY[1,2,3,4], 4)`